# How to debug a 500 error from javascript to Django that isn't hitting the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have the following javascript function that posts back some data to my Django backend:

```
// event_id/csrf_token is declared outside of this scope
function requestInivtation(some_param) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/requestInvitation/",
        data: {"event_id" :event_id.toString(), "some_param" : some_param, "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf_token},
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Requested.");
        }
    });
}
```

I've set up this view on the backend... Here's the urls.py entry:

```
url(r'^requestInvitation/$', views.requestInvitation, name='requestInvitation'),
```

and the view:

```
@login_required
def requestInvitation(request):
    print "This is a test."
    return HttpResponse()
```

When this javascript call is made, I am getting a 500 error back.  The data seems valid going into the function, and the URL routing seems to be ok.  I'm not sure what the next step is for debugging.  In the django console, the only thing I'm seeing is this:

```
[17/Aug/2014 08:26:43] "POST /requestInvitation/ HTTP/1.1" 500 9918
```

So my question is: How do I debug these 500 errors from javascript -> Django and how can I solve this scenario?

Comment: have you tried to use developers console in your browser? it should give you a lot of useful info

Comment: i can see the error in your urls.py. should be `views.requestInvitation.as_view()`

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)".  With respect to your 2nd comment, no other views I've built have required .as_view()?  Why would this one require it?

Comment: Is this is what you see in response tab? Probably you need to set `DEBUG` to `True` in your settings.py. Regarding second comment, yeah, my bad, I haven't noticed its not class based views

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov Debug = True is definitely set in my settings.py already, along with TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

Comment: If the dev console is not helping you, One thing you can do to debug is, either use cURL, or RestClient on Chrome or Firefox, and fire the request as a POST directly. You can see the response much easier. For this to work, of course DEBUG should be True. You can also see a stack trace on the runserver console, or apache/nginx logs running

Comment: @karthikr Nice, good suggestion.  I curled the request and got that the CSRF verification failed.  Interesting, since I'm passing along the token as part of the post request

Comment: How is `csrf_token` defined ? it should just be `{{csrf_token}}`

Comment: @karthikr Yup.  In the template, ``var csrf_token = "{{csrf_token}}";`` and in an external javascript file is the javascript in the orginal question

Comment: If CSRF verification is failed it must return 403 not 500 error. When you use curl to test you can't bypass the CSRF check and for that reason you see that error. When you use javascript the error is different than that from curl.

Comment: @V I thought maybe the same thing.  To try to get around that, I put a breakpoint right before the ajax call, copied the value of the csrf token, and pasted that into my curl request.  I don't know if this is valid or not though, so you might be right.

Comment: The suggestion of @karthikr is correct. You need to use your browser and it's developers tools to check the response from the server and to see the correct traceback. If you use Chrome/Chromium you can go to 'Network' then made the steps to execute the AJAX call and you will see the row indicating the failed request. Click on it and then click on the "response" or "preview" subtabs to see the response from Django.

Comment: If this is your local dev environment, you can also put a `pdb` statement inside the view to see if you are indeed hitting that view.

Comment: Oof.  Thanks guys.  I followed the tips you guys gave me, and it was due to conflicting views.  Having all of the views in one file makes it really easy to lose track of what already exists.  My bad.